# How to Route traffic through a VPN that is only available through another computer on the network?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

Network 1 has 2 computers, PC1 and PC2.  PC1 has access to a VPN.  PC2 Does not.  Is there a way that PC2 can route its traffic through the VPN on PC1?

a possible Idea that I came up with would be SSH Tunneling.  As long as I know a finite list of endpoints that I want to access through the VPN, I could set up specific SSH tunnels to those specific endpoints and access them through localhost:{port-number-i-defined-for-that-specific-endpoint}

Would that even work?  is there a cleaner setup that someone else could think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As you don't mention any operating system, I'll assume that it's all Linux).

You'll need to ensure that packet forwarding is enabled on PC1.  To do this permanently, add a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` (I called mine `local.conf`):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

You'll also want to set its iptables to do NAT, by editing `/etc/iptables.rules` (assuming you have an interface `up` rule to `iptables-restore` the rules file):

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
```

On PC2, you'll want to route traffic to your VPN via PC1.  Assuming it has a single Ethernet interface, add a `route` command to the `up` and `down` commands in your `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` (or to `/etc/network/interfaces` if you're using a single file for all interfaces):

```
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      broadcast 192.168.0.255
      pre-up iptables-restore </etc/iptables.eth0.rules
      up route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1
      down route del -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0
```

I've assumed above that PC1 should be `192.168.0.1` and PC2 should be `192.168.0.2`, and that your VPN appears as `10.x.x.x`; substitute your own values as appropriate.

You'll probably want to create the route by hand the first time, and only add it to the interface file when you're happy it's doing the right thing.