# Set up Windows PC to forward traffic through VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

Given a Windows 10 machine with a VPN client installed, is there any way to easily route traffic from other Windows 10 machines on the same local network through the VPN?

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1061363/how-to-route-traffic-through-a-vpn-that-is-only-available-through-another-comput), but using Windows instead of Linux.

Comment: By default, while connected to a VPN, you should already route traffic through the VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound the traffic from the PC1 opening the VPN connection will route through it, but I want to get traffic from PC2 going through the VPN using PC1 as a relay through the VPN.

Comment: Why don't you just connect both machines to the same VPN?

Comment: The VPN is installed and running on one machine, and I am not able to install it on the other machine

Comment: Traditionally you will be unable to connect to machines connected to a VPN server, unless the client on question, also is connected to the VPN.  Is there a specific justification that the client is unable to be connected to the VPN?